# How to change background by changing class name

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qtstylesheets

I have a window in Qt set up with some labels. All of them have a boolean property named "show_background" set to false by default. It also has a QSS file that sets a background when that is set to true:

```
*[show_background=true]{
    background-image:url(:/background.png);
    /* ... */
}
```

It works perfectly in the Qt Designer, but when I want to activate the backgrounds programatically, it doesn't work:

```
self.elementX.setProperty("show_background", True)
```

I have tried executing that piece of code before the window open and it works. But if I want to modify the property when the window is already opened, it does nothing.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Stylesheets are not automatically reevaluated when you change a property.
A workaround is to call `QStyle::unpolish()` followed by `QStyle::polish()` after you change the property.

See [this wiki article](https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets) for more details.